# One for the mySQL "EXPLAIN" experts

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

here's an <kbd>[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30266/5/2)</kbd> with 3 EXPLAIN on 3 different queries that give the same result.
To me the 3rd query looks best. but I am unsure about the "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY".
So my question is which one is really the best query?
Are there any other variations that give same result that are even better.
According to someone named @Strawberry, there is but @Strawberry haven't posted it.

After reading @BillKarwin's answer, I did this <kbd>[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30266/12/5)</kbd> to see which query is actually the faster (with that sample dataset).

Comment: Just create another `conversation` table and keep the reference to the last message. That's the best solution.

Comment: @zerkms good thinking, i never thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that EXPLAIN isn't necessarily the best indicator of the fastest query. It's just an *estimate* of the optimizer's best guess.

The best query can also be different, based on how much data you have in your tables, and how much competition for memory there is on your system due to queries running in concurrent threads.

So you should actually run those queries, don't just look at EXPLAIN alone. Use a [query profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profile.html) or the MySQL 5.6 [PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html) or [SHOW SESSION STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-status.html). Measure the performance both individually, and under load, to get a complete picture of the performance. There's also a new [optimizer trace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-tracing.html) feature, but this is subject to change.

Comment: cool, you mean something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30266/14/5? according to that sample dataset, the query that i thought was the worse was actually the quickest one.

Comment: Yes, but be careful about inferring too much about the best query when the tables have so few rows in them. It's common to get quite different results as your data grows.

Comment: I suspect that query would slow down as the data grows but i'll never know, profiling is great to know though thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a fourth solution, that is actually quite frequently used:

Introduce another `conversation` entity that would hold the conversation metadata like: the first message reference, the last message reference, etc

That way you would be able to fetch the data without any nasty joins or group by's

Comment: +1, i don't want to accept your answer just yet as I don't know if other ideas exists and i want to hear them all.

Comment: btw, is the 3rd query actually better than the 1st one? do you know for sure?

Comment: @Tin Tran: I think #3 is better than #1 indeed